# TypeError: Challenge() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a server and using flask as the webframework and I came across this error.
TypeError: Challenge() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
even though I send 3 arguments to Challenge

Here are the codes:

```
def login_required(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'Logged_In' in session:
            return test(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap

if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['button'] == 'Challenge':
            game = session['User'] + ',' + profUser + ',' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            return redirect(url_for('Challenge', game=game, white=session['User'], black=profUser))

@app.route('/<game>')
@login_required
def Challenge(game, white, black):
    if session['User'] == white:
        side = "white"
    if session['User'] == black:
        side = "black"
    else:
        side = None
    return render_template('game.html', game=game, user=session['User'], side=side)
```

Comment: Your function takes three arguments. You pass in `game`, but where do `white` and `black` come from?

Answer (score 1):

The route only specifies one argument:

```
@app.route('/<game>')
```

To get all three, you can do something like

```
@app.route('/<game>/<white>/<black>')
```

Comment: @dismal was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations and http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule, you can use `defaults` paramer:

```
@app.route('/<game>/<white>/<black>')
@app.route('/<game>', defaults={'white': None, 'black': None})
@login_required
def Challenge(game, white, black):
    pass
```

or just set default values for `white` and `black` parameters:

```
@app.route('/<game>/<white>/<black>')
@app.route('/<game>')
@login_required
def Challenge(game, white=None, black=None):
    pass
```